# deleting columns from a datatable with conditioning

Tags: c#, datatable

i have a datatable in which i have to delete all the columns, if the value of all the cells is "0" . the datatable has a final row, called Total in which i should verify the condition. i have tried this function:

`for (int counter = dt.Columns.Count-1; counter > 0; counter--)
         { if (dr[counter]=="0") 
           {dt.Columns.RemoveAt(counter);}
         }`

the schema of the DataTable is:
`  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bootstrap1"].ConnectionString);
                connection.Open();
                string sqlStatement = " the select query "

```
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
            sqlDa.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                //Pivot the Original data from the DataTable by calling the
                //method PivotTable and pass the dt as the parameter

                DataTable pivotedTable = ArangeData(dt);
                GridView1.DataSource = pivotedTable;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
}
private DataTable ArangeData(DataTable dt)
{
    DataTable newdt = new DataTable();
    SqlServerUserStore ss = new SqlServerUserStore();
    Televizioni channelslist = ss.GetChannelsList();
    DataRow dr = null;

    newdt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Sectors", typeof(String)));
    for (int i = 1; i < channelslist.televizioni.Count + 1; i++)
    {
        newdt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(channelslist.televizioni[i - 1], typeof(String)));
    }
    newdt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Total", typeof(String)));

    int lastsector = -1;

    int shuma = 0;

    bool first = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        int sector = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
        if (sector != lastsector)
        {

            if (first)
            {
                first = false;
            }
            else
            {
                dr[channelslist.idtelevizioni.Count + 1] = shuma;
                newdt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            lastsector = sector;
            dr = newdt.NewRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < newdt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                dr[j] = "0";
                dr[0] = dt.Rows[i][3];
            }
            shuma = 0;
            shuma += Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[i][2].ToString());
            dr[merrindeksinNgaIdTelevizioni(Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString()), channelslist) + 1] = dt.Rows[i][2];

        }
        else
        {

            dr[merrindeksinNgaIdTelevizioni(Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString()), channelslist) + 1] = dt.Rows[i][2];
            shuma += Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][2].ToString());
        }

    }

    dr[channelslist.idtelevizioni.Count + 1] = shuma;
    newdt.Rows.Add(dr);



    dr = newdt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = "Total";
    int shumatore = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < newdt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        shumatore = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < newdt.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            shumatore += Convert.ToInt32(newdt.Rows[j][i].ToString());
        }
        dr[i] = shumatore;

    }
     newdt.Rows.Add(dr);
     return newdt;
```

`

where dt is the DataTable. However, it seems not working, so i cannot understand what is going wrong. can anybody help me?

Comment: What is dr? Is it a DataRow? Is this the whole code used or do you have also an external loop here?

Comment: @Steve , dr is the Data Row. for the deleting procedure this is the code i am using. the point is that it does not express any error, it just doesn't delete the column.

Comment: I would try to add a ToString() before using that comparison, Strange that you don't have any exception

Comment: @Steve i already tried also with the ToString(), is the same result. actually i have tried another code before this one, which threw an \OutOfRange Ecxeption.

Comment: i suggest to use the debugger. Put a breakpoint inside that loop and check what value is stored there. Perhaps the value you are trying to compare is not "0" but "0.0" (if your previous question has anything to do with this one)

Comment: @HassanNisar yes, because the cell named "Total" has the total of the values of all the columns, and if this total is "0" , i have to delete the entire column from the datatable.

Comment: I understand. counter condition must be `counter >= 0` if you want first column as well.

Comment: @HassanNisar the first columns has the names of each row, is not needed in the counter.

Comment: Also @user3779463 can you show how you got `dr`. May be you are not referring to right datarow.

Comment: @HassanNisar the dr is declared as follows:  DataRow dr = null;

Comment: For example if it is last row in the datatable. It should be like `DataRow dr = dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1];`

Comment: @Steve after the breakpoint, i noticed that the loop continued until the fifth column, while i actally have 15 columns and the column nr. 10,12 and 13 should be deleted. can you help me with this issue?

Comment: @HassanNisar tried that, but however didn't work...

Comment: To help you we need to know the schema of the DataTable (column names and column type) and what is stored in the Total row

Comment: @steve i edited the code above. hope you can help me :)

Comment: @HassanNisar  i edited the code above. hope you can help me :)